# Python lxml - Normalize all elements subchildren in dictionary

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse a security OVAL XML definitions file in order to automatically execute tests.

What I'm trying to achieve is for each definition, convert the test criteria and criterions in a dictionary.

The criteria XML structure looks like below:

```
 <criteria operator="AND">
        <criteria comment="Affected IOSXE configuration" operator="AND">
          <criterion comment="ASR 1000 series router" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:5943" />
          <criteria comment="Affected IOSXE configuration" operator="OR">
            <criteria comment="Zone-based firewall configured" operator="AND">
              <criterion comment="Match TCP or UDP" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6071" />
              <criterion comment="ZBFW inspection enabled" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:5850" />
            </criteria>
            <criteria comment="NAT and PPTP ALG are enabled" operator="AND">
              <criterion comment="NAT configured" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6020" />
              <criterion comment="NAT enabled" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6146" />
              <criterion comment="PPTP ALG disabled" negate="true" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:5668" />
            </criteria>
            <criteria comment="NAT and TCP reassembly are enabled" operator="AND">
              <criterion comment="NAT configured" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6020" />
              <criterion comment="NAT enabled" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6146" />
              <criterion comment="Affected processor" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:5622" />
            </criteria>
            <criterion comment="EoGRE is enabled" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6003" />
          </criteria>
        </criteria>
        <criterion comment="IOSXE version is affected" test_ref="oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6178" />
      </criteria>
```

I'm able to retrieve and map the first level of criteria using code below:

```
# Add OVAL ID attrib in normalized Vulnerability dictionary
for idx, vuln in enumerate(vuln_list):
    vuln['oval_id'] = root.xpath("//ns:definition", namespaces=ns)[idx].attrib['id']

    criteria = root.xpath("//ns:definition[@id='" + vuln_list[idx]['oval_id'] + "']/ns:criteria/*", namespaces=ns)

    vuln['criteria'] = [crit.items() for crit in criteria]
```

This populates my dictionary with results below, obviously missing the nested children elements:

```
{'cisco_adv_id': 'cisco-sa-20131030-asr1000',
  'cisco_adv_url': 'http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20131030-asr1000',
  'criteria': [[('comment', 'Affected IOSXE configuration'),
                ('operator', 'AND')],
               [('comment', 'IOSXE version is affected'),
                ('test_ref', 'oval:org.cisecurity:tst:6178')]],
  'cve_id': 'CVE-2013-5547',
  'oval_id': 'oval:org.cisecurity:def:4321',
  'title': 'Cisco IOS XE Software Malformed EoGRE Packet Denial of Service '
           'Vulnerability'},
```

I could go over nested for loops and checking if the element has children with getchildren() but it doesn't sound like an optimal solution as each definition has one or multiple criteria/criterion elements.

Any ideas on how I could parse this more efficiently ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use recursion it is relatively easy.

for this first example, i tried to keep the same organization as yours: each criteria is a list containing attributes and children but both stored as dicts instead of tuples

```
def get_data(el):
    if el.tag =='criteria':
        data = {'criteria': [el.attrib]}
        for desc in el.iterchildren():
            data['criteria'].append(get_data(desc))
        return data
    else:
        return {'criterion': el.attrib}
```

the problem is that the data returned is not easily usable: each criteria can contain up to three dicts (attributes, criterion or criteria) and you'll have to make some tests to know which is which. in this second example you know in advance what a list contains: if the key is criteria you know you'll have a list of criteria-dicts.

```
def get_data(el):
    if el.tag =='criteria':
        data = {}
        data.update(el.attrib)
        for desc in el.iterchildren():
            key = desc.tag
            if not key in data:
                data[key] = []
            data[key].append(get_data(desc))
        return data
    else:
        return el.attrib
```

Comment: Thanks @bobrobbob the iterchildren method definitely makes  it easier.